# Using Eloquent to fetch data from a single table with foreign keys to two other tables - laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

please I have three Models: lecturers, levels, course.

lecturers table

```
| ID | Name_of_lecturer  
+----+----------------  
| 1 .| Prof John Doe  
+----+----------------  
| 2 .| Prof Jane Doe
```

Levels table

```
| ID | Name 
+----+----------------  
| 1 .| Level 1  
+----+----------------  
| 2 .| Level 2
```

Course table

```
| ID | level_id | lecturer_id | course_info
+----+----------+-------------+----------------------------------  
| 1  | 2        | 3             a topic in level 2 by lecturer 3
+----+----------+-------------+----------------------------------
| 2  | 5        | 6           | a topic in level 5 by lecturer 6
```

I am really confused on how to go about getting the lecturers details from the Levels Model for each individual course using Eloquent. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to read this documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Can you add your expected result on the end of the question?

Comment: I read the documentation and ran into various error. I want to be able to access it from the levels model, where i get all the courses and their respective lecturers. thanks.

Comment: There is a `BelongsToMany` relationship between `Lecturer` and `Level`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

Since one Lecturer can have many Courses you are looking at a one to many relationship. But since you are going from the Course (many) to the Lecturer (one) you're looking for this:

In your `Course` class add the following function:

```
public function lecturer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Lecturer::class);
}
```

That will allow you to use `$course->lecturer()` or `$course->lecturer->Name_of_lecturer` as you need.

Here's the relevant link to the Laravel Docs: [Eloquent: Relationships - One to Many (Inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

Answer (score -1):

If you are not so familiar with laravel's eloquent through Models, you can use query with JOIN (inner join or whatever you need).
For example:

```
$lecturersDetails = DB::table('course')->join('lecturers','id','=','lecturer_id')->get();
```

Comment: Your response does not use Eloquent